# Python: Extract Attribute within JSON data structure

Tags: python, parsing, ebay-api, simplejson

I am currently parsing eBay data using eBay public API, I have figured out the way to parse the JSON structure except for some JSON elements.

Here is the JSON structure that I am looking at:

```
  {u'itemId': [u'370640300983'], u'isMultiVariationListing': [u'false'], u'globalId': [u'EBAY-US'], u'title': [u'DELL Latitude D630 Core 2 Duo 2GHz 1GB 80GB CD-RW/DVD WiFi Notebook 14" Laptop'], u'country': [u'US'], u'shippingInfo': [{u'expeditedShipping': [u'true'], u'shippingType': [u'Calculated'], u'handlingTime': [u'1'], u'shipToLocations': [u'US'], u'oneDayShippingAvailable': [u'false']}], u'galleryURL': [u'http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/pict/3706403009834040_1.jpg'], u'autoPay': [u'false'], u'location': [u'Saint Paul,MN,USA'], u'postalCode': [u'55114'], u'returnsAccepted': [u'true'], u'viewItemURL': [u'http://www.ebay.com/itm/DELL-Latitude-D630-Core-2-Duo-2GHz-1GB-80GB-CD-RW-DVD-WiFi-Notebook-14-Laptop-/370640300983?pt=Laptops_Nov05'], u'sellingStatus': [{u'currentPrice': [{u'@currencyId': u'USD', u'__value__': u'99.99'}], u'timeLeft': [u'P0DT0H13M10S'], u'convertedCurrentPrice': [{u'@currencyId': u'USD', u'__value__': u'99.99'}], u'bidCount': [u'4'], u'sellingState': [u'Active']}], u'paymentMethod': [u'PayPal', u'VisaMC', u'Discover'], u'primaryCategory': [{u'categoryId': [u'177'], u'categoryName': [u'PC Laptops & Netbooks']}], u'condition': [{u'conditionId': [u'3000'], u'conditionDisplayName': [u'Used']}], u'listingInfo': [{u'listingType': [u'Auction'], u'gift': [u'false'], u'bestOfferEnabled': [u'false'], u'startTime': [u'2012-08-15T23:28:05.000Z'], u'buyItNowAvailable': [u'false'], u'endTime': [u'2012-08-20T23:28:05.000Z']}]}
```

Data that I am currently parsing

```
370640300983
DELL Latitude D630 Core 2 Duo 2GHz 1GB 80GB CD-RW/DVD WiFi Notebook 14" Laptop
{u'@currencyId': u'USD', u'__value__': u'99.99'}
```

Second Element:

```
{u'itemId': [u'170892723100'], u'isMultiVariationListing': [u'false'], u'globalId': [u'EBAY-US'], u'title': [u'Dell Latitude D620 Laptop Core 2 Duo 2GHz  1GB Ram No HDD INCOMPLETE'], u'country': [u'US'], u'shippingInfo': [{u'expeditedShipping': [u'false'], u'handlingTime': [u'1'], u'shippingServiceCost': [{u'@currencyId': u'USD', u'__value__': u'24.0'}], u'oneDayShippingAvailable': [u'false'], u'shipToLocations': [u'US'], u'shippingType': [u'Flat']}], u'galleryURL': [u'http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/pict/1708927231004040_1.jpg'], u'autoPay': [u'false'], u'location': [u'Hughesville,PA,USA'], u'postalCode': [u'17737'], u'returnsAccepted': [u'true'], u'viewItemURL': [u'http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dell-Latitude-D620-Laptop-Core-2-Duo-2GHz-1GB-Ram-No-HDD-INCOMPLETE-/170892723100?pt=Laptops_Nov05'], u'sellingStatus': [{u'currentPrice': [{u'@currencyId': u'USD', u'__value__': u'20.01'}], u'timeLeft': [u'P0DT1H10M35S'], u'convertedCurrentPrice': [{u'@currencyId': u'USD', u'__value__': u'20.01'}], u'bidCount': [u'2'], u'sellingState': [u'Active']}], u'paymentMethod': [u'PayPal'], u'primaryCategory': [{u'categoryId': [u'177'], u'categoryName': [u'PC Laptops & Netbooks']}], u'condition': [{u'conditionId': [u'3000'], u'conditionDisplayName': [u'Used']}], u'listingInfo': [{u'listingType': [u'Auction'], u'gift': [u'false'], u'bestOfferEnabled': [u'false'], u'startTime': [u'2012-08-18T00:25:30.000Z'], u'buyItNowAvailable': [u'false'], u'endTime': [u'2012-08-21T00:25:30.000Z']}]}
```

Parsed elements of the second element:

```
170892723100
Dell Latitude D620 Laptop Core 2 Duo 2GHz  1GB Ram No HDD INCOMPLETE
{u'@currencyId': u'USD', u'__value__': u'20.01'}
```

If you see In both iteration of my code I am unable to get the u'**value**: element parse and get the actual price extract from the data structure:

Basically instead of `{u'@currencyId': u'USD', u'__value__': u'20.01'}` I would like to get `20.01` as the parsed value. Should I be using regular expression to parse it or is there a better way to do it?

```
Here is my code:
  data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
  #print data
  for item in data['findItemsByKeywordsResponse'][0]['searchResult'][0]['item']:
    print item
    for itemId in item['itemId']:
      print itemId
    for title in item['title']:
      print title
    for price in item['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice']:
      print price
    print '\n'
```

Comment: What about changing that line to `print price['__value__']`?

Comment: brilliant may be you should submit as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You went that far into the objects and lists with the `[]` syntax to ask if you need regex to do one more of these steps? Am I missing something?

Comment: I actually overlook @RocketDonkey infact opened my eyes..?

Comment: Sure, just posted it. Happy it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Per comment above):

Try changing:

```
for price in item['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice']:
    print price
```

to

```
for price in item['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice']:
    print price['__value__']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
for price in item['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice']:
      print float(price["__value__"])
```

Of course, it's a horrible idea to use floats for money, so you should either use the `decimal` module:

```
from decimal import Decimal

for price in item['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice']:
      print Decimal(price["__value__"])
```

Or parse it into an integer price in cents:

```
for price in item['sellingStatus'][0]['currentPrice']:
      dollars, cents = price["__value__"].split(".")
      print int(dollars) * 100 + int(cents)
```